# Дублируются значения в переиспользуемом кастомном <select>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть страница на которой расположено два идентичных кастомных select.
Проблема заключается в дублировании выбранных данных. При клике на label во втором select, выбранное значение подставляется во второй и в первый select.
В console выводится сначала click по выбранному select -> записывается значение в input, после происходит click по другому select -> записывается значение в input. + в console выводятся все предыдущие итерации.

Первый select во вкладке Мои покупки, второй select находится во вкладке Мои баллы. Если я выбираю в select "Вчера", то это значение заносится во все select.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!-- Календарь для фильтрации чеков по дате -->
<div class="calendar__main d-fl">
    <div class="calendar__wrapper d-fl-col">
        <label class="calendar__label js-calendarLabelError">Необходимо выбрать дату</label>
        <input type="text" class="calendar__input js-calendar__input" readonly placeholder="Выберите дату">
        <div class="select__calendar-content js-selectContent d-fl-col">
            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect0" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect0" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="yestrday">Вчера</label>

            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect1" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect1" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="last-week">Неделю назад</label>

            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect2" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect2" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="last-month">Месяц назад</label>

            <input type="text" class="select__option js-calendarDateRange" id="calendar__date-picker" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" data-language='ru' placeholder="Выбрать дату" name="calendar-check">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn__calendar js-showCalendarDate">Показать</button>
</div>



// функция для выбора option
  function chooseCalendarDate() {
    let calendarInput = document.querySelectorAll(".js-calendar__input"); // input в котором будет выбранный option
    let radioBtnCalendarLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".js-select__option"); // label по которому происходит click для выбора данных
    let calendarDateRange = document.querySelector(".js-calendarDateRange"); // input на котором открывается календарь

    // при клике на input открывается контент с option
    calendarInput.forEach((inputCalendar, index) => {
      inputCalendar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
        inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active"); // контент с option
        mainContent.classList.add("active");

        // закрытие контента при клике на option + выбор данных
        radioBtnCalendarLabel.forEach((labelBtn) => {
          labelBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            inputCalendar.value = e.target.textContent; // заносим новые данные в input
            inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active"); // контент с option

            console.log(e.target);
            console.log(inputCalendar.value, inputCalendar, index);
          });
        });

        // закрытие контента при клике на пустое пространство
        mainContent.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          if (e.target !== inputCalendar && e.target !== calendarDateRange) {
            if (calendarDateRange.value.length > 0) {
              inputCalendar.value = calendarDateRange.value; // заносим новые данные в input
              calendarDateRange.value = ""; // обнуляем данные для дальнейшего открытия
            }
            mainContent.classList.remove("active");
            inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active"); // контент с option
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  chooseCalendarDate();
```

Comment: Возможно, из-за постоянного переподписывания на эвент клика происходит накладывания эвентов. Попробуйте исключить переподписывания.